# How to have a user enter a string, and then sort through an array to display a string depending on the code entered

Tags: java, project

I am working on my first CIS final and am running into some issues with the program I have tried creating.  I am wanting the program to prompt the user to enter a 2 character code, and sort through an array of strings.  Depending on what code gets entered it will display that corresponding array.

I keep running into some compile errors, and have tried different ways of setting this up.  I think I am overlooking one of the more simple concepts..

```java
package finalproject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalProject {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String chargeback = sc.nextLine();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the chargeback code : ");
    }
    String[] code = new String[10]; {
        code [0] = "Unathourized online purchase";
        code [1] = "Merchandise not receieved";
        code [2] = "Not as described";
        code [3] = "Inocrrect Amount";
        code [4] = "Credit not received";
        code [5] = "Paid by other means";
        code [6] = "Cancelled Reccuring";
        code [7] = "Liability Shift";
        code [8] = "EMV Fallback";
        code [9] = "EMV counterfit";

        switch (chargeback) {
        case "UO":
            System.out.println(code[0]);
            break;
        case "MN":
            System.out.println(code[1]);
            break;
        case "ND":
            System.out.println(code[2]);
            break;
        case "IA":
            System.out.println(code[3]);
            break;
        case "CV":
            System.out.println(code[4]);                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                
        case "PM":                                                                                                
            System.out.println(code [5]);                                                                         
            break;                                                                                                
        case "CR":                                                                                                
            System.out.println(code[6]);                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                
        case "LS":                                                                                                
            System.out.println(code[7]);                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                
        case "EF":                                                                                                
            System.out.println(code[8]);                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                
        case "EC":                                                                                                
            System.out.println(code[9]);                                                                          
            break;                                                                                                
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it simply displays run:
Enter the chargeback code : 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

It never lets me enter anything into the input to sort through anything.  Any sort of guidance would be appreciated as I am rather new to this, and still trying to understand it.

Comment: `String chargeback = sc.nextLine();` Put that line in the main function. Also there's an extra `}` after `System.out.println("Enter the chargeback code : ");`that has nothing to do there. I don't know how your code compiled but I'd consider using an IDE if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Map usage is better approach here.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html
>
> public interface Map Key,Value
>
> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>
> This interface takes the place of the Dictionary class, which was a totally abstract class rather than an interface.

```
public class FinalProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> codeMap = initMap();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the chargeback code : ");
        String chargeback = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(codeMap.get(chargeback));
    }

    private static Map<String, String> initMap()
    {
        // ---- init of code mapping.
        Map<String, String> codeMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        codeMap.put("UO","Unathourized online purchase");
        codeMap.put("MN","Merchandise not receieved");
        codeMap.put("ND","Not as described");
        codeMap.put("IA","Inocrrect Amount");
        codeMap.put("CV","Credit not received");
        codeMap.put("PM","Paid by other means");
        codeMap.put("CR","Cancelled Reccuring");
        codeMap.put("LS","Liability Shift");
        codeMap.put("EF","EMV Fallback");
        codeMap.put("EC","EMV counterfit");
        // ----
        return codeMap;
    }
}
```